# ApplicationDbContext thinks that DomainEvent is an entity but it is not

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-5.0

> Using context 'ApplicationDbContext'.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'DomainEvent' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943.

ApplicationDbContext thinks that DomainEvent is an entity, but it is not. It fails my migrations. What does make it look like so?

```cs
public abstract class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<DomainEvent> DomainEvents { get; } = new Collection<DomainEvent>();
    
    public void AddDomainEvent(DomainEvent eventItem)
    {
        DomainEvents.Add(eventItem);
    }

    public void RemoveDomainEvent(DomainEvent eventItem)
    {
        DomainEvents.Remove(eventItem);
    }
}

public class Bot : Entity, IAggregateRoot
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}

public interface IAggregateRoot
{
}

public abstract class DomainEvent : INotification
{
    public DateTime DateOccurred { get; protected set; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}

public class BotCompletedEvent : DomainEvent
{
    public BotCompletedEvent(Bot completedItem)
    {
        CompletedItem = completedItem;
    }
    
    public Bot CompletedItem { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IMediator mediator) 
        : base(options)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    public DbSet<Bot> Bots { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    
    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new())
    {
        var entitiesWithEvents = ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity>()
            .Select(e => e.Entity)
            .Where(e => e.DomainEvents.Any())
            .ToList();

        foreach (var entity in entitiesWithEvents)
        {
            var events = entity.DomainEvents;
            entity.DomainEvents.Clear();

            foreach (var domainEvent in events)
            {
                await _mediator.Publish(domainEvent, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        return SaveChangesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
}

public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
}
```

Comment: See [Excluding types from the model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-types?tabs=data-annotations#excluding-types-from-the-model)

Comment: @vernou, thanks but what makes it think that it is an entity? https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/master/src/Clean.Architecture.SharedKernel/BaseDomainEvent.cs Ardalis' project doesn't do that.

Comment: EF Core start from the DbContext to discover entities and browse all child entity (child is from class' members)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `INotification` for your domain events type.

```
public ICollection<INotification> DomainEvents { get; } = new Collection<INotification>();
```

Since it is now an interface, it will be ignored by EF Core. See [Domain events: design and implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation).

Comment: You meant `public ICollection<INotification> DomainEvents { get; } = new Collection<INotification>();`?